# mysql group by time : how to select the first milestones as datetime in the result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `datetime` column in my table, and I just want to group by time slice, minutes, hours or others ...
But I want to get each first milestone as datetime type in the result, rounded to the hour.

An example, with a 8h time slice

```
     date           | brand | total
2020-01-18 07:20:00     A       5
2020-01-18 09:17:00     B       1
2020-01-18 13:45:00     A       5
2020-01-18 14:00:00     B       7
```

with the query :

```
select what? , brand, sum(total) as total_8h from table group by brand,
YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date), HOUR(date) DIV 8
```

to obtain :

```
     date           | brand | total_8h
2020-01-18 07:00:00     A        5
2020-01-18 09:00:00     B        8
2020-01-18 13:00:00     A        5
```

My tables are big, so I must care about mysql functions on each line which could impact performances.

Comment: What is a "milestone"?  Why are you aggregating if you want a row?

Comment: What makes these 8-hour time slices if 07:00 and 09:00 are separate? If 00:00 - 07:59 is the 1st slice, and 08:00 - 14:59 is the 2nd slice, then 09:00 and 13:00 would both be grouped together.

Comment: here the milestone is the first datetime in the slice, rounded to hour.

Comment: @kmoser 3 timeslices in a day here : 0:00/7:59 & 8:00/15:59 & 16:00/23:59

Comment: @troubadour Then why does your desired output show 09:00 and 13:00 in separate groups? Shouldn't they both be in the 2nd group (8:00/15:59)?

Comment: @kmoser I see what you mean : the lines could define themself what are 8h-slices, the result would be 2 lines : `2020-01-18 07:00:00       A          10` and `2020-01-18 09:00:00       B          8`, it would be ok too, but the `group by` would be more tricky for this floating timeslice of 8h, and maybe performances poorer.

Comment: Why `07:00:00` and `09:00:00`? The 1st time belongs to the 1st 8hrs so it should be `00:00:00` and the 2nd belongs to the 2nd 8hrs so it should be `08:00:00`.

Comment: @forpas here I consider sliding slices defined by the first appearance of a brand, it's maybe a better solution for me that fixed slices as described in my second comment here. So, for brand A, 07:20:00 defines the beginning of a 8h slice, so the A at 13:45:00 belongs to the same slice since 8h have not elapsed yet, that's why the total is 10 in result. But I fear that the corresponding query will be tricky...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it without date functions.
I use [`TIMESTAMPADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd), [`HOUR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) and [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, HOUR(date) DIV 8 * 8, DATE(date)) date_8h, 
       brand, 
       SUM(total) as total_8h 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY date_8h, brand
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=86ceab2469fc3ae1bce2c6d303b762d3).
Results:

| date_8h | brand | total_8h |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-18 00:00:00 | A | 5 |
| 2020-01-18 08:00:00 | A | 5 |
| 2020-01-18 08:00:00 | B | 8 |

Comment: Yes @forpas :) date computation which is used in the group by, unavoidable. I'll try perfs in my big table. Thanks! 
If we dig a solution for the sliding slice, I guess there would be a second nested select for the date of first appareance of a brand for grouping, perfs will be poorer.

Comment: Without succes to compute a sliding slice of 8h staring at the first date, I can get the first date in the absolute slice (0/8h 8h/16h 16/24h) by :  `SELECT min(date), brand, SUM(total) as total_8h FROM tablename GROUP BY TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, HOUR(date) DIV 8 * 8, DATE(date)), brand`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first record in each timeslice, you can use `lag()` or `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date(date), hour(date) div 8 order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This won't be particularly fast on a large table.